# How to check for logical item combinations using t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to check whether a worker have all required skills. This is done by comparing worker set of skills with a set of skills that is required. So, to make it more clear, here is the DDL of the tables I have:

```
CREATE TABLE [WorkerSkills](
    [WorkerId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SkillName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) GO

CREATE TABLE [SkillCombinator](
    [SetId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SkillCombinator] [varchar](5) NOT NULL
) GO

CREATE TABLE [RequiredSkills](
    [SetId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SkillName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) GO
```

and here is the sample data:

```
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (1, 'B')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (1, 'C')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (2, 'D')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (2, 'X')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (3, 'E')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (4, 'A')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (4, 'B')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (4, 'H')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (4, 'I')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (5, 'A')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (5, 'B')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (5, 'C')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (5, 'E')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (5, 'G')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (5, 'H')
INSERT [WorkerSkills] ([WorkerId], [SkillName]) VALUES (5, 'I')

INSERT [SkillCombinator] ([SetId], [SkillCombinator]) VALUES (1, 'AND')
INSERT [SkillCombinator] ([SetId], [SkillCombinator]) VALUES (2, 'OR')
INSERT [SkillCombinator] ([SetId], [SkillCombinator]) VALUES (3, 'AND')

INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (1, 'B')
INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (1, 'C')
INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (2, 'D')
INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (2, 'E')
INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (2, 'F')
INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (3, 'G')
INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (3, 'H')
INSERT [RequiredSkills] ([SetId], [SkillName]) VALUES (3, 'I')
```

This means that there are 3 sets with each having 3 skills defined.

```
set 1: A and B and C
set 2: D or E or F
set 3: G and H and I
```

And there are workers with following skills:

```
worker 1: A, B, C
worker 2: D, X
worker 3: E
worker 4: A, B, H, I
worker 5: A, B, C, E, G, H, I
```

Now, the problem is to write a function in Sql Server 2008 that accepts **WorkerId** and **SetCombinator** parameters and returns a value indicating whether Worker has all required skill.

*Sample input 1:*

```
WorkerId: 1
SetCombinator: OR
```

This means that all sets should have **OR** combinator, i.e.:

```
set 1: A and B and C
OR
set 2: D or E or F
OR
set 3: G and H and I
```

The result should be **true** since Worker has skills that correspond to set #1.

*Sample input 2:*

```
WorkerId: 4
SetCombinator: OR
```

The result should be **false**.

*Sample input 3:*

```
WorkerId: 1
SetCombinator: AND
```

This means that all sets should have **AND** combinator, i.e.:

```
set 1: A and B and C
AND
set 2: D or E or F
AND
set 3: G and H and I
```

The result should be **false** since Worker has skills that correspond only to set #1, but not for 2nd and 3rd sets.

*Sample input 4:*

```
WorkerId: 5
SetCombinator: AND
```

The result should be **true** since Worker has skills that correspond for all sets.

Any ideas how this function should look like?

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that skills in RequiredSkills table are not constants, they will be often modified, and the number of these skills is also dynamic. So the solution with hardcoded values will not work.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent question and providing DDL & DML!

Comment: do yo have any feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is the best solution I've found so far.

```
create function fnMatchedToSkillsSet
(
 @WorkerId int,
 @Condition varchar(3)
)
returns table
as
return (
 with x as
 (
  select
   sc.SetId,
   nullif(case
    when sc.SkillCombinator = 'AND' and count(distinct ws.SkillName) = count(*) then count(distinct ws.SkillName)
    when sc.SkillCombinator = 'OR' then count(distinct ws.SkillName)
   end, 0) as SkillsCount
  from
   dbo.SkillCombinator sc join
   dbo.RequiredSkills rs on rs.SetId = sc.SetId left join
   dbo.WorkerSkills ws on ws.WorkerId = @WorkerId and ws.SkillName = rs.SkillName
  group by
   sc.SetId, sc.SkillCombinator
 )
 select
  case
   when @Condition = 'AND' and count(SkillsCount) = (select count(*) from dbo.SkillCombinator) then 1
   when @Condition = 'OR' and count(SkillsCount) > 0 then 1
   else 0
  end as Result
 from
  x
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for you so far. I hope it is something that you can work on and develop further to match your problem.
I've used bitwise logic - but I am no expert with this, and there may be others here who could improve on this.

```
DECLARE @WorkerID       BIGINT  = 1,
        @LogicalCase    BIT     = 1,    --  [0 = OR], [1 = AND]
        @SkillScore     INT     = 0,
        @isTrue         BIT     = 0

SELECT @SkillScore  =   SUM (
                                CASE    WHEN SkillName = 'A' THEN 1
                                        WHEN SkillName = 'B' THEN 2
                                        WHEN SkillName = 'C' THEN 4
                                        WHEN SkillName = 'D' THEN 8
                                        WHEN SkillName = 'E' THEN 16
                                        WHEN SkillName = 'F' THEN 32
                                        WHEN SkillName = 'G' THEN 64
                                        WHEN SkillName = 'H' THEN 128
                                        WHEN SkillName = 'I' THEN 256
                                END
                            )
FROM WorkerSkills
WHERE WorkerID = @WorkerID


IF @LogicalCase = 0
BEGIN
    IF (@SkillScore & 7 = 7)                                                            --      set 1: A and B and C 
    OR ( (@SkillScore & 8 = 8) OR (@SkillScore & 16 = 16) OR (@SkillScore & 32 = 32) )  --  OR  set 2: D or E or F
    OR (@SkillScore & 448 = 448)                                                        --  OR  set 3: G and H and I 
    BEGIN   
        SET @isTrue = 1
    END
END
IF @LogicalCase = 1
BEGIN
    IF (@SkillScore & 7 = 7)                                                            --      set 1: A and B and C 
    AND ( (@SkillScore & 8 = 8) OR (@SkillScore & 16 = 16) OR (@SkillScore & 32 = 32) ) --  AND set 2: D or E or F
    AND (@SkillScore & 448 = 448)                                                       --  AND set 3: G and H and I 
    BEGIN   
        SET @isTrue = 1
    END
END


SELECT @isTrue
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! Sorry, but I forgot to mention that skills are not constants. I added an update to my post.

Comment: The code I posted is not meant to be a final solution. It is merely a premise or suggestion for logic, illustrating how bitwise operations can be used. Your implementation may differ altogether. In certain cases, because of the limitation of bitwise operations (size of INT), the approach may be completely non-feasible. If bitwise is feasible, you can store the integer representative of the binary score in the RequiredSkills table to account for them being non-static.

Answer (score 0):

might not be the most efficient but it works for any number of skills and combinations:

```
declare @workerid int =5 -- input param
declare @setcombinator varchar(3) ='AND' -- input param

declare @skillsleft varchar(max)
declare @result varchar(10)
declare @getsets cursor
declare @set int

set @getsets = CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct SetId FROM SkillCombinator
OPEN @getsets
FETCH NEXT FROM @getsets INTO @set
-- set result by default
IF(@setcombinator='OR') set @result='FALSE' else set @result='TRUE'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN -- compares each skillset against worker's and determine match or mismatch

if (select skillcombinator from skillcombinator where setid=@set) = 'AND'
    BEGIN --needs all the skills in the set
        SET @skillsleft=
        (select count(*) from
        (select skillname from RequiredSkills a 
        join SkillCombinator b on a.setid=b.setid 
        where a.setid=@set
        except
        select skillname from workerskills where workerid=@workerid) t)
        -- override default depending on the logical combinations
        if (@skillsleft = 0 and @setcombinator='OR') set @result='TRUE' 
        if (@skillsleft > 0 and @setcombinator='AND')set @result='FALSE'
    END

if (select skillcombinator from skillcombinator where setid=@set) = 'OR'
    BEGIN --needs at least one of the skills in the set 
        SET @skillsleft=
        (select count(*) from
        (select skillname from RequiredSkills a 
        join SkillCombinator b on a.setid=b.setid 
        where a.setid=@set
        intersect
        select skillname from workerskills where workerid=@workerid) t)
        -- override default depending on the logical combinations
        if (@skillsleft > 0 and @setcombinator='OR') set @result='TRUE'
        if (@skillsleft = 0 and @setcombinator='AND') set @result='FALSE'
    END

FETCH NEXT FROM @getsets INTO @set
END
select @result
CLOSE @getsets
DEALLOCATE @getsets
```

Comment: The idea of this solution is read each set and determine type 'and' or 'or'. If the former, the worker in question needs all the skills in the set and if also the setcombinator is 'OR' then one hit it's enough to make it true. If the latter, the worker just need one of the skills in the set and again if the setcombinator is 'OR' one hit is enough to make it true. Conversely if we are working under setcombinator 'AND' one miss will be enough to make it false; that's why I started with default 'False' for setcombinator 'OR' and 'True' for setcombinator 'AND.

Comment: This looks quite good, but the problem is that it uses CURSOR, which are not allowed in our company coding guidelines. I'll now post the solution which seems to work fine an do not use CURSOR. Anyway thanks a lot for your response!